# Navigating System Settings with Applescript (in Ventura)

Tags: windows, button, settings, system, pane

I have been learning Applescript for several weeks — not a difficult task for a long-time programmer. One thing I am trying to do is to change system settings using Applescript. I have been searching every resource I can find, have read the Applescript online manual from cover to cover, explored many chat rooms that discuss this ... and I can find absolutely nothing about how to identify the different elements in the System Settings application. I have seen many pieces of code with lines like "... button 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of pane 1 of window 1 ..." But I can find no information on how to correlate this to what I see when I open System Settings manually. I have successfully been able to open a pane of my choice, and display a list of its UI elements (which don't correlate in any clear way to what I see visually in System Settings); but that's as far as I can get. Can someone explain, or direct me to a good tutorial that explains, how to under stand what "group 1" means, or "menu bar 1" or "button group 1" or splitter group 1" etc.? Until I can understand this, I am completely lost at trying to navigate through the settings, and to then be able to set the setting of my choice. Thanks for any help!